# Using a hyper ledger network without tls causing timeout when invoking a chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting the below error when I invoke my smart contract

```
Error: Error endorsing invoke: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error 
executing chaincode: Failed to execute transaction (Timeout expired while 
executing transaction) - <nil>
```

I am able to query the chaincode and this chaincode has worked on networks with TLS but now without it Im getting the error.

We removed TLS as we were having troubles with grpc connections when making calls from the node SDK. So possibly we could hit two birds with one stone.

How to deal with this error above?

And how to deal with TLS in the node app when making GRPC calls.

Comment: please provide peer logs

Comment: and if you can the configuration of the peer and how did you disabled the TLS part.